# PHP ldap_get_entries returns null but only on one system not on another

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to connect to Active directory and validate my user which works and the I retrieve a certain field which returns and employeecode that stored in AD for our payroll/ESS application, this code has been working on multiple different clients but suddenly at one client the code runs through until it get to the `ldap_get_entries`, the `ldap_search` ran successfully but nothing is getting returned in `get_entries`

If checked some similar problems where people changed `sAMAccount` to uid or email in the filter but that hasn't helped me solve this, does anyone maybe have an idea whatI missed that would make this code fail on one system but work fine on others
the magic happens in the second function (`RetrieveADEntry`), the first(`Authenticate`) is just to show my connection

```
    public function authenticate()
    {
        error_reporting(0);
        //10.0.4.22
        $this->ldapConnection = ldap_connect($this->mHost, $this->mPort);
        if(isset($this->ldapConnection))
        {
            if(trim($this->mUsername) === "")
            {
                $this->mErrorCode = ERR_USERNAME_REQUIRED;
                $this->mConnected = false;
                return false;
            }
            else if(trim($this->mPassword) === "")
            {
                $this->mErrorCode = ERR_PASSWORD_REQUIRED;
                $this->mConnected = false;
                return false;
            }
            echo "pre bind";
            ldap_set_option($this->ldapConnection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
            ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
            if ($this->mGroup == null)
            { 
                $ldaprdn = $this->mPrdn . "\\" . $this->mUsername;
            }
            else
            {
                $ldaprdn = 'cn='.$this->mGroup.$this->mPrdn . "\\" . $this->mUsername;
            }
                $mConnected = ldap_bind($this->ldapConnection, $ldaprdn, $this->mPassword);
                if ($mConnected)
                {
                    $this->retrieveADEntry();
                    echo "Binded";
                    if ($this->mErrorCode == UNAUTHORIZED)
                    {
                        $this->mErrorCode = UNAUTHORIZED;
                        $this->mConnected = false;
                    }
                    else if ($this->mErrorCode == ERR_LOGIN_FAILED)
                    {
                        $this->mErrorCode = ERR_LOGIN_FAILED;
                        $this->mConnected = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->mErrorCode = SUCCESSFUL;
                        $this->mConnected = true;
                        if ($data->{"rlogcompanycode"} != ''){
                            $this->setCompanyCode(trim((string)$data->{"rlogcompanycode"}));
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Not binded";
                    $this->mErrorCode = ERR_LOGIN_FAILED;
                    $this->mConnected = false;
                }
                return $this->mConnected;

        }
        else{
            $this->mErrorCode = ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED;
            $this->mConnected = false;
            return false;
        }

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    }
    private function retrieveADEntry()
    {
        //$ldap_base_dn = 'DC='.$this->mDC.',DC='.$this->mDomain;
        $ldap_base_dn = "OU=group,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=za";
        $filter = "";
        $attr = array(
            $this->mField,
            "sAMAccountName",
        );
        $filter .="(sAMAccountName=$this->mUsername)";
        $search_results = ldap_search($this->ldapConnection,$ldap_base_dn, $filter);
        //For each account returned by the search
        if (FALSE !==  $search_results ){
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($this->ldapConnection, $search_results);
            $values = ldap_get_values($this->ldapConnection,$search_results, $attr);
            $access = 0;
            //For each account returned by the search
            echo "succesfull query";
            echo $entries['count'];
            echo $this->mUsername;
            var_dump($values);
            for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++)
            {
                echo "in loop";
                var_dump($entries); 
                if (strpos( $entries[$x]['memberof'][0], $this->mGroup)) //Check if member is part of specified group
                {
                    echo "GroupCheck1";
                    $access = 1;
                    $group =  $this->mGroup;

                }

                if ($this->mGroup == null)
                {
                    echo "GroupCheck2";
                    $access = 1;
                }
                echo "PostGroupChecks";
                echo $access;
                if ($access != 0)
                {
                    echo "access";
                    echo $this->mField;
                    echo $entries[$x]['sAMAccountName'][0];
                    if (!empty($entries[$x][$this->mField][0]))
                    {
                        $this->setEmpkey($entries[$x][$this->mField][0]);
                        echo $entries[$x][$this->mField][0];
                    }
                    echo "return succesfull";

                    $this->mConnected = true;
                    $this->mErrorCode = SUCCESSFUL;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "No Access";
                    $this->mConnected = false;
                    $this->mErrorCode = UNAUTHORIZED;

                } //END for loop
            }
            //END FALSE !== $result
            ldap_unbind($ldap_connection); // Clean up after ourselves.

        }
        else
        {
            $this->mConnected = false;
            $this->mErrorCode = ERR_LOGIN_FAILED;
        }
        return $this->ldapEntry;
    }
```

PS. I also wrote a C# script for our desktop app which works perfectly fine on this system just like on all the rest and doesn't give this issue

Comment: Does your `$ldap_base_dn` actually have spaces in your code, or is that just a typo in your question? There should be no spaces after the commas. That would make it not return any results.

Comment: Check what `$filter` is when the search is made. Is there actually any account with that `sAMAccountName`? Also check the `$ldap_base_dn`. Does the account with that `sAMAccountName` actually have that base DN in its own `distinguishedName`?

Comment: @GabrielLuci my $ldap_base_dn does not have spaces just a type as I did not want to add the actual address to the site, our address gets read in through a config file, I have checked that sAMAccountname matches the username that I input under the users attributes, it also has it in it's distinguished name, the frustrating part is that this code runs fine on our other systems and my C# code which works the same for our dekstop app reads the same config input and it also works fine on this same system so just not sure why our php returns nothing

Comment: Check that `$filter` ends up being what you expect it to be. (`echo $filter` just before you execute the search)

Comment: @GabrielLuci thanks, tried that but still the same, filter seems to function fine, it looks like the filter finds the correct Sammaccount but the get entries itself does not get populated, not sure if it could be related to certain securities as it works fine on our other systems

Comment: @GabrielLuci also just thanks for the advice this has me stumped and the extra set of eyes helps a lot

Comment: Any LDAP query (regardless of the programming language) connects to a server, uses a base DN, query string, and a scope (usually `subtree` if you don't specify). If it works in C#, but not in PHP, then one or more of those things are different. Make sure those four things match between your C# and PHP implementations.